# Can I add header to GET request when I using Image object to generate the request?

Tags: javascript

I'm using img object to generate HTTP GET request, and I want to add a header to it.

Can it be done using Javascript code?

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
// here I want a code that add the header to the request...
img.src = "https://sidanmor.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/sparta.jpeg?w=816";
```

I want the ability to add header to the request like I have here using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var innerXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
innerXhr.open("GET", "https://sidanmor.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/sparta.jpeg?w=816", true);
innerXhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
innerXhr.send(null);
```

**Note:** here I'm setting the `Cache-Control` header, but I want the ability to set any header that I want...

Comment: I want to set the request headers, not the response headers

Comment: No there is no way to add headers client side for `img.src` url's unless you go through ajax , fetch etc to get image data and convert to a data url.